# file reading from different directory

Tags: file-io, io, lua

I have a separate folder `Input` for the text files. i'm trying to read the lines in a certain file 'train.txt'. So how do i do it using this code?

```
for line in io.lines '???' do

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`io.lines`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-io.lines) takes an optional argument to represent which file it iterates. Since this file is in a different folder, use an absolute path, or a proper relative path. For instance, in Unix-like system, you can use `"/some/path/Input/train.txt"`.

```
for line in io.lines("/some/path/Input/train.txt") do
    --print(line)
end
```

Comment: the OP asked for reading the file in a directory called Input. Just changing "train.txt" to "Input/train.txt" fixes this.